# Can I set the state and call a function on one button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a button and when I click on it I'm using `onClick` to set the state and call a function.  When I pair the two actions together, it seems to only set the state.

If I remove the sitting the state function, the `handleClick` function works.  Can you have multiple function calls in an `onClick` function?  I searched around here and found a post stating that you could, not sure if my code is incorrect.

```
class OverviewRender extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = { 
             Selected: 'MainMenu',
             name: ''
         }
       }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("OverviewRENDER update name: " + this.state.name);
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let helpFileName = this.state.name;
        helpFileName = helpFileName.toLowerCase().trim();
        //Cap the first letter in the name and add the rest of the name 
        helpFileName = helpFileName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + helpFileName.substr(1);
        this.props.handleHelpChange(helpFileName);
        console.log("pressed " + helpFileName);
    }
```

The button calling `onClick`...

```
  <RaisedButton 
     label="Load Default Values"
     name="One"
     value={this.state.name}
     onClick={() => {this.handleClick.bind(this), this.setState({ name: 'One' })}} 
     style={buttonStyle}
   />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're not executing the function. `Function#bind` returns a new function with the specified `this` and other supplied arguments bound. You have to execute it. Anyways, since you're using an arrow function, there's no need to bind anyway. Lastly, just set state inside `handleClick`, and pass in any variables you need to:

```
onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'One')}
```

And `handleClick`:

```
handleClick(e, num) {
  this.setState({
    name: num
  }, () => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let helpFileName = this.state.name; //or num
    helpFileName = helpFileName.toLowerCase().trim();
    //Cap the first letter in the name and add the rest of the name 
    helpFileName = helpFileName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + helpFileName.substr(1);
    this.props.handleHelpChange(helpFileName);
    console.log("pressed " + helpFileName);
  });
}
```

Also note that I'm setting state *first*, then using a callback because `setState` is asynchronous. You have to wait until it is set to access it and get the right value.

Comment: I have 10 buttons, I can't set the state inside handleClick statically with 'One' - has to be associated with the name of the button, or somehow from the button

Comment: @user3622460 Then you could pass it into the function `handleClick`. `(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'One')` then in `handleClick`: `handleClick(e, num) { ... this.setState({ name: num }) }` though I would reevalute your design if you need strings like that.

Comment: That handles passing in the string, when I run the changes I'm still at the same point.  It will update the state and but 'helpFileName = this.state.name' is not returning 'One' as expected.  For some reason it's returning blank.

Comment: I have it setup like this because I'm rendering various different objects of buttons to the screen.  Each group of buttons is associated with an entry in a database.  When you click the button it calls a search function that find the entry and renders it out below.  Couldn't really think of a better way to handle it because the buttons do not link directly to a component, they are basically just searching a database and another component is rendering those results to the screen.

Comment: @user3622460 Well, I've updated my answer for the state problem. Honestly, couldn't you just do `let helpFileName = num` too?

Comment: Gotcha - Thanks for helping me understand how these calls are occurring.  I'll change this to pass in the String from the call for use, but thanks and accepting

Answer (score 1):

You could either have the `handleClick` set the state, as mentioned in the previous answer, or your `onClick` could call `handleClick` in the callback:

```
<RaisedButton 
 label="Load Default Values"
 name="One"
 value={this.state.name}
 onClick={() => { this.setState({ name: 'One' }, this.handleClick.bind(this) }} 
 style={buttonStyle}
/>
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I have in the post?

Comment: @user3622460 - No. What you were doing was calling 2 functions. This one first calls `setState` which then executes `this.handleClick()` as it's callback. This is because `setState` isn't immediate.